# Proving set |A ∪ B ∪ C| = |A△B△C| + 6.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am studying discrete math and I stumbled upon a proof I couldn't prove. Can someone help me with this one?

"Assume that $A,B,C$ are three sets with no elements in all three sets. Assume further that the number of elements that lie in precisely two of the sets are $6$. The set $A\,\triangle\,B\,\triangle C$ is defined as the set of elements which lie in precisely 1 or 3 of the sets A,B,C. Prove that $|A \cup B \cup C| = |A\,\triangle\,B\,\triangle C| + 6.$"

I know that $|A \cup B \cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|−|A \cap B|−|B \cap C|−|C \cap A|+|A \cap B \cap C|$.
but I don't know how to prove the above where there is $|A\,\triangle\,B\,\triangle C| + 6$.
Can someone help me and show me how to do this?

Comment: The symmetric difference consists of all elements that are in either of the sets, but not both. Here, we know that six is the number of elements in the intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, inclusion/exclusion doesn't really help you. Define
$U_i$ to be the subset of $A\cup B\cup C$ which occur in exactly $i$ of the sets $A$, $B$, $C$; the $U_i$'s are disjoint. Since every element of $A\cup B\cup C$ is in one, two, or three of the sets, we have
$$(*) \quad |A\cup B\cup C| = |U_1|+|U_2|+|U_3|.$$

By definition, $A\Delta B\Delta C$ is just $U_1 \cup U_3$, so $|A\Delta B\Delta C|=|U_1|+|U_3|$. We're also given $|U_2|=6$. Plug these values into the right-hand side of $(*)$ and the desired result follows.

(Remark: the problem assumed $U_3=\emptyset$ but this turned out to be unnecessary.)

Comment: im not sure if i understand what you are trying to prove here

Comment: Edited and hopefully clarified the answer.

Comment: im wondering if this is sufficient proof because it seems so vauge, im not sure, is it easier to do with venn diagrams?